# NodeJS wait for three requests before response

Tags: android, node.js

I have three Android devices with the same app, but I need that the three devices start the app simultaneously.

I have a server too, and the app exchange data with this server (developed in NodeJS).

I thought that all devices can connect to the server and wait until a response. But I don't know how to do it with Node. I used clusters in Node but it didn't work, because I don't know how to synchronize all these 3 clusters.

How can I do that? Another idea?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean, you need the three devices to start the app simultaneously?

Comment: Can you post your code.

Comment: Yes, I need to start it simultaneously. I did what bbbonthemoon said. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's easy to implement with generic events in node.js. Create some special event, and keep requests without response until the event is triggered, what obviously happens when 3rd request is received. node.js is very powerful in that.

Comment: I did it and it worked. I created an Array and put all responses inside then I respond when all requests are in the Array. Someting like that: <code>responses.push(res);
 if(responses.length == number_devices)</code>